# Exibir apenas a div correspondente ao botão clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de exibir apenas a div correspondente ao botão clicado.

Por padrão a tab `tab-dados` inicia ativa, mas se o botão `name="hidraulica"` for clicado esconde a div `tab-dados` e aparece a `tab-hidraulica`. Assim por diante.

Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado

```css
.tab-dados, .tab-hidraulica, .tab-civil, .tab-eletrica, .tab-comentarios {
  display: none;
  background: #3880ff;
}

.active{
  display: block; 
}

footer{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="app">

  <div class="tab-dados active">
    Dados
  </div>

  <div class="tab-hidraulica active">
    hidraulica
  </div>

  <div class="tab-civil">
    civil
  </div>

  <div class="tab-eletrica">
    eletrica
  </div>

  <div class="tab-comentarios">
    comentarios
  </div>


  <footer>
    <button class="btn-tab blue bd1" type="button" name="dados">Dados</button>
    <button class="btn-tab blue bd1 " type="button" name="hidraulica">hidraulica</button>
    <button class="btn-tab blue bd1 " type="button" name="civil">civil</button>
    <button class="btn-tab blue bd1 " type="button" name="eletrica">eletrica</button>
    <button class="btn-tab blue" type="button" name="comentarios">comentarios</button>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria dessa maneira

```
$('footer button').each(function(e){ // Seleciono os botoes do <footer>

    $(this).click(function(e){ // Para cada botão adiciono um evento de click

        let nome = $(this).attr('name'); // Pega o nome do botão clicado

         $('.active').removeClass('active');
        // Removo a classe active das divs ativas

        $(`.tab-${nome}`).addClass('active'); 
        // Adiciono a classe active na div referente ao name do botão

    })
})
```